# How to handle open file popup using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

When I navigate to certain URL, the browser prompts me to open a file:

[image]

How can I select "Open" when controlling the browser via selenium? Can I set some options to the webdriver to automatically open files? I am using Microsoft Edge.

My current solution is to use `keyboard` module and press tabulator and enter to click the open-button, but I would like to do this so that the `keyboard`-module wouldn't be needed and I would be able to run selenium in headless mode.

Also, if there is another way to do this than by using selenium, feel free to suggest. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try this:  `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()`. You have to import this in order to write the line `from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should understand if it is a browser prompt or a prompt from the website. In the first case, Selenium can't handle it.

If it is a website prompt, you should try

```
IAlert alert = _DRIVER.SwitchTo().Alert();

//accept the alert
alert.Accept();

//dismiss the alert
alert.Dismiss();
```

Wrote it C#, but I think is the same thing in Python.

Comment: Driver can't find an alert dialog. I think it is a browser prompt. Are you sure there is no way of handling browser prompts via edge options that are passed to the webdriver?

Comment: @juhat I also think it's a browser prompt because of what it asks you. And I'm sorry but you can't handle that with Selenium ... I've spent a lot of time there in the past and the most reliable solution I found was to refresh the page. Alternatively, you could use arrows but I don't recommend this method at all because it doesn't have control over what it does and above all you don't know what clicked and where ...